# How to get Token from DotNetOpenAuth OAuthAuthorizationServer sample with C#?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

How to get Token from DotNetOpenAuth OAuthAuthorizationServer sample with C#?
I'm running the sample provided in Github.
I want to get the token, for now unsuccessfull. Always get a 400, bad request.
The request I've sending is as follows:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost:50172/OAuth/Token");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("client_id", "sampleconsumer");
        request.Headers.Add("client_secret", "samplesecret");
        request.Headers.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        request.Headers.Add("code", "teste");
        request.Headers.Add("redirect_uri", "");

        WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //400 -  bad request here.
        }
```

I have no skills with OAuth, this is my first attempt. I've searched a lot but still a bit confuse.

Comment: First you need to set redirect uri and 2cnd you sure that you want to send this request to localhost? And your try catch stuff makes no complete sense - use response.ensuresuccess() method in the try block

Comment: I'll set redirect uri a try it again. And yes, I'm using localhost for tests purpose only. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use headers for the ClientID and the other stuff, put it into the body.

This is how I get Token with the [Client Credential Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...
var url = "http://localhost:50172/OAuth/Token"
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";

string data = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" +
    "sampleconsumer&client_secret=samplesecret";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();

newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
newStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(result);
}
```